# Rails 4 how to call accessible_attributes from Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm trying this tuto on Rails cast ([Importing csv Excel file](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true)). And I'm having an error on this line `product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)`

`undefined local variable or method`accessible_attributes' for #`

this is my model.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'roo'
  validates_presence_of :price
  #attr_accessible :name, :price, :released_on #I removed this line (rails 4)


  def self.to_csv(options = {})
    CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
      csv << column_names
      all.each do |product|
        csv << product.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
      end
    end
  end

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      product.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path)
    when ".xls" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::Csv.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

end on my controller I defined the product_params

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(:name, :price, :released_on)
  end
```

my csv that I'm trying to import looks like this:

```
id,name,realased_on,price,created_at,updated_at
1,Acoustic Guitar,2012-10-03,3456.54,2013-12-09 00:00:23 UTC, 2012-12-08 23:45:46 UTC
```

Comment: `undefined local variable or method `accessible_attributes' for #<Class:0x000000042b3640>`

Comment: In the self.import(file) function I added this line instead: `row.to_hash.slice(Product.attribute_names)` but I'm getting an validation error : `Validation failed: Price can't be blank`

Comment: you can just use it in old school way - `gem 'protected_attributes'`

Comment: thks Okliv for the post!

Comment: But I don't know why it's telling me the 'Price can't be blank' Does Rails trying to read the first line or the last line? Do I have to ask this Question in another StackoverFlow' Post?

Comment: Check your schema - probably your column is set to be not nullable.

Comment: On my rails dbconsole: .schema products `CREATE TABLE "products" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "name" varchar(255), "released_on" date, "price" decimal(2,0), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime);`

Comment: I had this same issue and the problem was a space AFTER the column name so the import did not recognize the column name.

Comment: I came here from the same railscasts video.

Comment: does anyone have this working on Rails 4 and have their code hosted on GitHub? I would love a complete example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `accessible_attributes` fetch that columns which are declare `attr_accessible` in model but in rails 4 they have removed the `attr_accessible` from model and used the strong_parameter instead of that so for this make an method of same name `accessible_attributes` in his model then inside that method declare that columns array which are you want. Such as:

```
def accessible_attributes
 [col1_name, col2_name, ....]
end
```

Comment: Are you you is [col1_name, col2_name]  i changed it for [:name,:lastname] but is not working

Comment: Any help much appreciated

Comment: In Rails 5 I add to add "self." to the method definition, and pass names as strings
`def self.accessible_attributes
 ['col1_name', 'col2_name', '...']
end`

Answer (score 10):

In working on this Railscast under Rails 4.1, I got the method to work by replacing accessible_attributes with row.to_hash.keys.

```
def self.import(file)
   spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
      product.save!
    end
end
```

Comment: That's the same as saying `product.attributes = row.to_hash` since you are getting all the keys from the `row` object. It will work, but the intention of the Railscast code was to take only the columns from the row that have matching attributes in the Product model. (Often spreadsheets have more columns than you'll need in your model.) Since Rails 4 doesn't use `attr_accessible`, you have to explicitly name the keys you want as in the accepted answer above.

Comment: What do you change to not upload the ID just continue the sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Using the accepted solution as is didn't work out for me. I needed to add "self." to the method definition to make it work.

Another way, if the only place you are calling accessible_attributes is within self.import, is defining the fields you are looking for as a local array variable.

```
def self.import(file)
    accessible_attributes = ['my_attribute_name1','my_attribute_name2', '...']
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      cae = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      cae.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      cae.save!
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the previous question that why validation message shows "Price can't be blank". I think it may due to that the data is saved as General format in Excel. I encountered a similar issue and the error message went away after I changed it to text format. I don't know the reason but give it a try.