# Rails importing csv into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

My question is not mainly about how to import the file. I have a problem with the create method in my controller. I am importing some tasks and the `Task.new` takes `task_params` as an argument. This method is as follows:

```
def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:date, :description)
end
```

This causes an error when I run it. I get `parameter missing` error in `task_params` method. Is there any way to fix this and allow files through?

**EDIT** Here is the full trace:

```
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb:173:in `require'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:78:in `task_params'
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:33:in `create'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__2649129199446340827__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__104897348271024377__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Import method:**

```
  def import
      Task.import(params[:file])
      redirect_to tasks_path, notice: "Tasks Imported Successfully"
  end
```

And then `Task` model has the following:

```
def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
    Task.create! row.to_hash
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
        row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
        task = find_by_id(row['id']) || new
        task.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
        task.save
    end
end
```

Comment: can you please include some `stacktrace` or `backtrace`

Comment: please include your `params` too

Comment: my `params` are the ones in the `task_params` method. Just `:date` and `:description`. I'll include my import method.

Comment: if you don't have `task` in the params then it would keep raising an exception

Comment: You are calling in your model row.to_hash before defining row, in Task.create! Perhaps it's a line you forgot to comment out...

Comment: Thanks that was my bad. It was supposed to be deleted however that does not solve the problem.

Comment: And you are completely sure your csv headers are 100% compatible to your model definition?

Comment: Yes just checked again headers are complete match. However out of curiosity won't the error be different if headers did not match?

Comment: I'm retiring now, goodnight. Check this post however, I think it's similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854347/rails-4-how-to-call-accessible-attributes-from-model

Comment: if there is no `task` key in your params you would keep getting this exception

Comment: How can I fix it then?

Comment: Thanks man solved it - answer below. I cannot believe such a simple typo took me a whole night to solve. I guess I'm still a new to rails but this was unacceptable. A big thanks for your helps and apologies for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys solved it. The main issue was the import form. If anyone has the same problem make sure you are redirecting to the correct `action` in your `controller`. This was my previous form tag:

```
<%= form_tag tasks_path, multipart: true do %>
```

**But that was not correct**. It should be redirected to `import` action in your controller if you have defined one:

```
<%= form_tag import_tasks_path, multipart: true do %>
```

You can make sure you have defined this `action` by running `rake routes |grep import`

I hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

These lines (properly adjusted to your code) should work for skipping validations in your Create action in your controller

```
@task=Task.new(task_params)
@task.save(:validate => false)
```

However, skipping validations is hardly recommendable...

Comment: the OP did not ask of how to skip validations, he is complaining of an error

Comment: You sure hurried a lot in downvoting.. Shouldn't you wait for his answer first?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I really prefer not to skip validation.

Comment: Ok bjhaid, you were right this once, but you see how the params are irrelevant, so I feel not so bad about my answer...