# Error while importing .xlsx file using roo gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I got the following error:

```
NoMethodError in ClientsController#table
undefined method `phone' for nil:NilClass
```

This occurs when I try to import .xlsx,.xls or .csv files into ruby on rails application.

Model code is given below:

```
attr_accessible :name, :kind, :address_attributes, :emails_attributes, :phones_attributes, :attachments_attributes

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
      client = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
      client.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
      client.save!
    end
  end

  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
      when '.csv' then Roo::Csv.new(file.path)
      when '.xls' then Roo::Excel.new(file.path)
      when '.xlsx' then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path)
    else
      raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
```

Controller code is given below:

```
  def import
    Client.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to clients_path, notice: "Clients imported."
  end
```

apps/Services/config/application.rb file include the following code:

```
require 'csv'
require 'iconv'
```

gem file include the following:

```
gem 'roo', '~> 2.1.0'
gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
gem 'roo-xls'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use this syntax for **Roo** gem:

```
def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else 
    raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Comment: I applied your suggestion @marwen. It's not working:
RuntimeError in ClientsController#import
Unknown file type: client1.xls

Comment: Are you using `carrier_wave` for the file upload?

Comment: Yes, I am using carrier_wave for file uploading

Comment: I applied your modification.It's not working, the following error arises:
undefined method `file' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00555aec003b78>

Comment: This tells that you are not using `carrier_wave` here. We well revert back to your previous code and inverstigate it more.

Comment: I am using carrier_wave for file or image uploading situation. It doesn't use in file importing situation

Comment: the following error arises:
Excel support has been extracted to roo-xls due to its dependency on the GPL'd spreadsheet gem. Install roo-xls to use Roo::Excel.

Comment: One step closer. Add `roo-xls` to your `Gemfile` and bundle it

Comment: another issue arise:
undefined local variable or method `options' for #<Class:0x007f7ef933cc80>

Comment: Another issue occurs:
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)

Comment: This maybe occurs with the version of **Roo**, keep only `file.path` as argument and remove `, nil, :ignore`.

Comment: New issue arises:
NameError (undefined local variable or method `accessible_attributes' for #<Class:0x007f3b7d59b9a0>)
The error code section is added above.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854347/rails-4-how-to-call-accessible-attributes-from-model

Comment: Now the imported data is stored into the database, but the nested_attributes can't store to the database.Such as :address_attributes, :emails_attributes, :phones_attributes. @marwen please note this issue

Comment: @geethujoseph Clearly you are following a tutorial, to get it working YOU HAVE TO: 1) Follow exactly 2) Use the same **GEM VERSIONS**. If you have done that, you won't have so much trouble

Comment: I am using following gems @marwen:
gem 'roo', '~> 2.1.0'
gem "iconv", "~> 1.0.3"
gem 'roo-xls'

Comment: You can reformat you question with the **extensive** details, and I will take a look at it.