# undefined local variable or method error Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have been referring [RailsCasts #396](http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel?autoplay=true) for importing data from csv, xls, xlas files. According to the railscast (Rails 3.2.9) the import method is

```
def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    product = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    product.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    product.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Csv.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xls" then Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

but since Rails 4x implements strong params I was getting `undefined local variable or method 'accessible_attributes'` error
So I looked up and found this stackoverflow question [Rails 4 how to call accessible_attributes from Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854347/rails-4-how-to-call-accessible-attributes-from-model), according to the answer I tried

```
def attr_names
  [user_id, last_name, first_name, last_name_kana, first_name_kana, created_at,created_by, updated_at, updated_by, del_flag]
end

def self.import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    user = find_by(user_id: row["user_id"]) || new
    user.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*attr_names)
    user.save!
  end
end

def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, csv_options: {encoding: "SJIS"})
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Still getting same error, only this time it is `undefined local variable or method 'attr_names'` . Thanks in advance

Comment: you need `def self.attr_names`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks... How silly of me !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Being on the model, you should make it `self.attr_names`. Alternatively, all your methods there being self, you could extend self, like so:

```
extend self

def attr_names
  [user_id, last_name, first_name, last_name_kana, first_name_kana, created_at,created_by, updated_at, updated_by, del_flag]
end

def import(file)
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    user = find_by(user_id: row["user_id"]) || new
    user.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*attr_names)
    user.save!
  end
end

def open_spreadsheet(file)
  case File.extname(file.original_filename)
  when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path, csv_options: {encoding: "SJIS"})
  when ".xls" then Roo::Excel.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  when ".xlsx" then Roo::Excelx.new(file.path, nil, :ignore)
  else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
user.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*column_names)
```